# Parsing xml with empty namespace

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I use `lxml` to parse well-formatted xml:

```
<search-results xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
                xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0/"
                xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
                xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <opensearch:totalResults>0</opensearch:totalResults>
    <opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
    <opensearch:itemsPerPage>0</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
    <entry>
        <error>Result set was empty</error>
    </entry>
</search-results>
```

I am interested in the text inside `error`.

I was using the following code:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.fromstring(xml) # xml is above xml

ns = {'opensearch': "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"}
print doc.xpath('//opensearch:totalResults', namespaces=ns)[0].text
```

which works fine to get a `0`, but what should I do for `<entry>`, which doesn't seem to be in a namespace? I tried adding the empty namespace, which I think is associated with `"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`:

```
ns = {'opensearch': "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/", 'empty': "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
print doc.xpath('//entry/error', namespaces=ns)[0].text
```

But this results in an `IndexError`, because there is no list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use that `empty` alias you gave to the empty namespace inside the expression:

```
ns = {'opensearch': "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/", 'empty': "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
print doc.xpath('//empty:entry/empty:error', namespaces=ns)[0].text
```